# Add resx text to model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, resx

I want to replace the hard-coded message from string from the resx file in 
my project. When I have simple text like column header I do it like following and it's working OK ("Name" is the key in the resx file).

```
[Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(PStr)),Required]
```

Now I want to change the Invalid name text with resx that I've gotten.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\s?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\s*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Name")]
```

How should I do that?

When I try it like the following I get an error at compile time:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\s?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\s*$", ErrorMessage = "ERROR_Valid", ResourceType = typeof(PStr))]
```

Comment: It would be useful to include the compile time error since you have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ErrorMessageResourceType you should be using ErrorMessageResourceName btw.